# Unexpected path being shown in Prompt

Tags: zsh

[image: Prompt with unexpected path being shown]

On zsh shell (remote shell), I am seeing an unexpected path being displayed on the right hand side. I don't have any such component in the prompt variable. What can be the cause?

```
function parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/[\1]/p'
}

setopt PROMPT_SUBST

export PROMPT='[dev] %~ $(parse_git_branch)
# '
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are wondering, why the `$~` does not output your working directory. To focus on this problem, try a prompt which has **only** this entry, because the other parts don't seem to matter here. I would also do an explicit `setopt PROMPT_PERCENT`, though I would have expected that this is the default anyway. Note that you can test your prompts easily and without explicitly changing the `PROMPT` variable by doing a `print -P promptstring`, for instance `print -P '%~'`.

Comment: As an aside, use `git branch --show-current` rather than parsing the output of `git branch`.

Comment: Also, search `man zshcontrib` for `vcs_info`, which will show you how to configure your prompt to show a lot of VCS information without having to explicitly call any `git` commands directly.

Comment: Check if `RPROMPT` or `RPS1` is set.

Comment: @chepner, thanks! The problem was resolved after reset of RPROMPT

Comment: Since your problem was solved, can you close this question, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prompt at the right side of terminal is displayed in zsh if the variables `RPROMPT` or `RPS1` are set. Check if they are set by running `echo $RPROMPT` or `echo $RPS1`. If one (or both) is non empty, then it's possible that it is getting set somewhere else.

Add the lines `export RPROMPT=''` and `export RPS1=''` at the end of the file `~/.zshrc`.